# matplotlib show a expection?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib to plot the result of values in two arrays, but the result shows a point (0, 0) which is not in my array. The other points are correct but only this one. Below is my code.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

j=0
x=0.6

resx = np.zeros((100, 100))
rr=np.zeros((1, 100))
for r in np.linspace(2.4, 4, 100):
    rr[0,j] = r
    for i in range(0, 100):
        x = r * x * (1-x)
        resx[j,i] = x
    plt.plot(rr[0,:], resx[:,j], '.')
    j=j+1
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors; your resulting array cannot contain anything, let alone (0, 0)

Comment: Sorry, I have modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is how you populate your two arrays `rr` and `resx`. Printing out both arrays before the plotting via

```
print rr[0,:]
print resx[:,j]
```

will give you arrays of the form

```
[ x_1 ... x_(j) x_(j+1) ... x_100 ]
[ y_1 ... y_(j) y_(j+1) ... y_100 ]
```

where `x_i=y_i=0` for `i>j`. If this is intended and you would like to avoid plotting the point (0,0) (which you by the way plot a bunch of times), you could simply not plot the last `100-j` values:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=0.6

resx = np.zeros((100, 100))
rr=np.zeros((1, 100))
for j,r in enumerate(np.linspace(2.4, 4, 100)):

    # Populate x-array
    rr[0,j] = r

    # Populate y-array
    for i in range(0, 100):
        x = r * x * (1-x)
        resx[j,i] = x

    # Only plot last n-j values     
    plt.plot(rr[0,:j], resx[:j,j], '.') 

plt.show()
```

which will give you something like this:

[image]